# Parallels between story of Abraham handing his wife Sara over to the Pharaoh (Gen 12) and Israel then spending 400 years slavery in Egypt

Tags: genesis, exodus, abraham, joseph, egypt

In my study of the books of Genesis and Exodus, I have noted what appear to be clear parallels between the events which take place between Abraham and his wife Sara and the future events which take place with Abraham's descendants Israel from Exodus 37 onwards.

My question is to ask what is the link, meaning, and significance of these parallels?

To explain further: Taking [**Gen 12:10-20**](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+12%3A10-20&version=NIV) as a starting point. Abraham encounters a famine in the land and heads down into the land of Egypt. There he pretends Sara is not his wife and hands her over to the Pharoah and receives great reward and possessions from the Pharoah. Subsequently, God then punishes Pharoah for taking Sara, sending "serious disease" upon his house. Pharoah then hands Sara back to Abraham and he comes out of Egypt.

This story effectively seems to mirror - almost as an allegorical or prophetic foretelling of exactly what takes place later with Israel starting from [**Genesis 37**](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2037&version=NIV) with Josephs story.

Here due to disliking him - Joseph is sold by 11 brothers into slavery and eventually through a series of events including his interpreting dreams predicting 7 years of abundant harvest followed by 7 years of famine he rises to become the Vizor of Egypt. When the famine strikes the land in Caanan - just like with Abraham - Israel (Jacob and his sons) end up migrating to Egypt to survive the famine. Joseph is able to use his position to benefit them and establish them in the land. Then subsequently as we move into the book of Exodus Israel is taken as a slave by Egypt for approx 400 years / or 4 generations **(Gen 15:16)**. After which just like in Abraham's story, God then sends plagues and disease on Egypt and Israel comes out of Egypt with great possessions.

To me, it seems clear that the two stories are tightly linked and intertwined. They seem to be mirrors of each other with "Sara" the "Barren wife" (Isaiah 54) effectively representing "Israel" in the story. My question is about the deeper meaning and significance of this link.  Is there any theological or scholarly examination or discussion of this parallel?

Could it be that Abraham / Sara in Egypt in Gen12 is a prophetic foretelling (or allegorical description) of what later takes place with Jacob and his sons and the subsequent generations? That this is something God wanted to bring to pass and so Abraham's story is basically prophetically "role-playing" the future events? This would potentially also line up with other events involving Sara such as her being over to the King in the land of Philistine and also the birth and mock sacrifice of Isaac (Which most see as a parallel for the sacrifice of Christ).

Alternatively, I also noted that **Gen 15:16** says that Israel will spend 4 generations in Egypt. Is it possible that this time in slavery is a punishment for Abraham's sin by handing over his wife to the Pharoah in Gen 12? With God basically punishing the future generations of Israel for Abraham's sin - visiting the sin of the father on the sons for 3-4 generations?

Alternatively, is there other agreed upon or discussed significance \ meaning to this parallel in the stories?

Comment: The stories maybe seen as parallel because of the underlying theology of the authors throughout the Bible that blames man for their slavery and fallen state; and shows God as the rescuer. It doesn't mean one is an allegory of the previous; though we find ample midrash parallels in prophetic interpretation by the Gospel authors. You shouldn't try to see unnecessary parallels when it is not there. Abram didn't do any sin there. Try to search Talmud and other sources on the passages for background.

Comment: These are all parables of Christ going to the earth in order to bring out the bride. E.g. Sarah was hidden in Egypt then uncovered as Abraham's wife and brought out. Same for Jacob going to Aram and Abraham's servant going to Aram to bring back Rebekkah, etc.

Comment: Thanks. The Old Testament is saturated with ‘parallels’ such as you’ve highlighted, and they form a crucial foundation for understanding (as opposed to merely interpreting.)Torah. The ‘thanks’ is for identifying this one - was new to me!

Comment: @Dave - Yes since seeing this and also making the connection with Isaiah 54 (Barren woman) I've been studying Sara's story through Genesis now with new eyes. That the events that take place between her and Abraham may have a lot more prophetic meaning significance. Potentially being a kind of "prophetic role play" for future events of Israel. Was interested to know if there had been any scholarly analysis of her story before.

Comment: If you are looking for a Midrashic parallel to Christ prophecy, then it is a subjective interpretation. You can interpret as you wish, similarly to the out of Egypt I called my son.

Comment: @xmarshallx Oh yes! The complete ‘picture’ of Sara has huge significance, and once you start ‘seeing’ it it just keeps on getting deeper. However if looking for reference, I would struggle to identify a single source - one of those ‘things’ you slowly pick up over time, a little at a time, from numerous sources.